# Network Sniffer in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp, packet-sniffers

---

Recently I completed my network sniffer for the company that I am currently working with.

I want to know:

- Is there any way to edit the captured packets before reaching the destination? (UDP/TCP)
- Is there any other procedure to capture packets?

---

### Here is my code template/procedure:

**1.** At first, when loading I get all the devices/hostnames on the computer.

```
IPHostEntry HostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry((Dns.GetHostName()));
```

**2.** For sniffing the socket to capture the packets has to be a raw socket, with the address family being of type internetwork, and protocol being IP.

```
mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
```

**3.** Bind the socket to the selected IP address.

```
mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(TEXT-OF-YOUR-HOST-ENTRY), 0));
```

**4.** Set the socket  options.

**5.** Capture outgoing packets to byte[] array.

```
mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, YOUR-TRUE-BYTES, YOUR-OUTGOING-BYTES);
```

**6.** Start receiving the packets asynchronously.

```
mainSocket.BeginReceive(BYTE-DATA, 0, BYTE-DATA-LENGTH, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(YOUR-RECEIVE-FUNCTION), null);
```

**7.** Analyze/Parse the bytes received. And don't forget to call another to BeginReceive so that we continue to receive the incoming packets.

**8.** Finally for parsing, you can create your own class or using the already invented classes/dlls to study your captured packages.

---

> ### Thats all I have.
>
> - I hope this helps for someone trying to start some network sniffer in    C#.
> - I hope that someone shows me the better ways to do this.
> - Also is there any chance to edit the packages I captured before they reach their destination?
>
> Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Wireshark (it uses the WinPCAP library) and the C# Wrapper for Pcap (https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net), in which you can implement and invoke Protocol Decoders and save traffic as a standard `.pcap` file? Why not use Wireshark / `tshark` for all packet capture in the first place?

Comment: Firstly, I looked the Pcap.Net before but in this case you really don't need to count on it. C# libraries can work as well. And Step.5 is an equivalent to SIO_RCVALL constant of Winsock 2.

Second, we need to develop our own network sniffer for special purposes/customization. And as far as I can say, wireshark is no different than any other network sniffer, in this case, ours can capture all as well. All I wanted to learn any chance of improvement and any chance of editing the packets before they reach their destination ip. Thank you for your comment I totally forgot to mention Pcap =)

Comment: This solution cross-platform?

Comment: What you shared is less useful in real world scenarios, as long as the traffic goes high enough, as it fails to utilize the actual highly efficient API exposed by the operating systems. If the company you served decided to go this way, then it seems to fail to understand the industry very well.

Comment: This post was created 7 years ago, with the intentions of helping "someone trying to start some network sniffer in C#". I was aware of the industry requirements but it was targeted for an internal use case and I can say that this small software achieved what I was trying to do. But you are right, this solution is inefficient and it is probably even unusable under the heavy traffic. Thank you for the comment @Lex-Li.